# dnf/yum installs an old version of a transitive dependency

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum, dnf

The package **java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7** requires **nss** (any version as I could check with repoquery)

If you check the list of available versions of that package

```
# dnf list --showduplicates nss
nss.x86_64    3.41.0-5.el8
...
nss.x86_64    3.79.0-10.el8_6
```

However, when you install the **java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless** package, the oldest possible version of *nss* gets installed

```
# dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7.x86_64
Installing:
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless  x86_64   1:1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7
Installing dependencies:
 ...
 nss   3.44.0-15.el8
 nss-softokn   3.79.0-10.el8_6 
 nss-softokn-freebl   3.79.0-10.el8_6
 nss-sysinit  3.44.0-15.el8
 nss-util  3.79.0-10.el8_6
```

Why if there is a newer *nss* version available an older version is installed?

NOTE: This behaviour started some months ago I don't know why, previously the latest was installed

EDIT: check one by one, all the dependencies from **java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7** installing them separately to see if any of them has *3.44.0-15.el8* as required version of nss, and did not find any

EDIT 2: There is also no Epoch number on nss package and if you try to install default version it will download the latest

EDIT 3: tried with --best option with same results

EDIT 4: more details

```
$ dnf repoquery --requires --resolve java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1:1.8.0.352.b08-2.el8_7.x86_64
...
nss-0:3.79.0-10.el8_6.x86_64
```

Comment: Does your machine have a yum configuration that pulls its updates from a on-prem or cloud based update server?  It may be that only that old version is available to dnf so it just pulls that.  For example, we have a spacewalk server that hosts our rpms but it hadn't been updated in some time so installing packages only adds what was available the last time it was updated.

Comment: @JosephIshak I am actually using the UBI8 minimal base image from redhat, you can absolutely replicate this behaviour by installing dnf or yum, using also default repos

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that something requires `nss-sysinit` which is available only in 3.44 version and `nss-sysinit` requires `nss` of the same version. Which is 3.44.